# Use inherited member operator instead of free one

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, overload-resolution

Suppose there is a free `operator*` defined somewhere in the namespace `ns`:

```
namespace ns {
    struct Dummy {};

    template <typename T>
    Dummy operator*(T&&) {
        return {};
    }
}
```

In a different place there is a base class in the same namespace, that defines member `operator*`:

```
namespace ns {
    template <typename T>
    struct Base {
        T x;

        T& operator*() { 
            return x;
        }
    };
}
```

And a lot of types derived from it. They behave identically, but must be distinct, for elsewhere templates need to be specialized on them:

```
namespace ns {
    template <typename T>
    struct DerivedA : Base<T> {};

    template <typename T>
    struct DerivedB : Base<T> {};

    template <typename T>
    struct DerivedC : Base<T> {};

    // etc
}
```

When I try to use `operator*` on a derived class:

```
ns::DerivedA<int> d;
*d = 42;
```

GCC yells at me "FOOL! Thou shan't assign `int` to `Dummy`!", which apparently means that free `operator*` is used instead of the member one in the base class.

I have no control at all over free operator, and can't move derived classes to different namespace.

How can I fix this without duplicating `operator*` in each derived class?

Comment: Can't you just call explicitly d.operator*() = 42;?

Comment: @Jasper, no, all of this is a part of EDSL, and such long and ugly notation would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, you can do this:

```
template <typename T>
struct DerivedA : Base<T> {
    using Base<T>::operator*;
};
```

Long answer: in order to figure out what `*d` to call, we have to determine all the viable functions (§13.3.2):

> From the set of candidate functions constructed for a given context (13.3.1), a set of viable functions is
>   chosen, from which the best function will be selected by comparing argument conversion sequences for the
>   best fit (13.3.3). The selection of viable functions considers relationships between arguments and function
>   parameters other than the ranking of conversion sequences.

There are two:

```
template <typename T>
Dummy operator*(T&& );

T& Base::operator*();
```

In order to figure out which one to pick, we have to determine which "implicit conversion sequence" (§13.3.3.1) is better:

> An implicit conversion sequence is a sequence of conversions used to convert an argument in a function call
>   to the type of the corresponding parameter of the function being called.

which for our first option is an "Exact Match", and for our second overload option is (§13.3.3.1.6):

> When the parameter has a class type and the argument expression has a derived class type,
>   the implicit conversion sequence is a derived-to-base Conversion from the derived class to the base class.
>   [ *Note*: There is no such standard conversion; this derived-to-base Conversion exists only in the description of
>   implicit conversion sequences. —*end note* ] A derived-to-base Conversion has Conversion rank

The ranking of the conversion sequences is (§13.3.3.1.1.3):

> Each conversion in Table 12 also has an associated rank (Exact Match, Promotion, or Conversion). These are
>   used to rank standard conversion sequences (13.3.3.2). The rank of a conversion sequence is determined by
>   considering the rank of each conversion in the sequence and the rank of any reference binding (13.3.3.1.4). If
>   any of those has Conversion rank, the sequence has Conversion rank; otherwise, if any of those has Promotion
>   rank, the sequence has Promotion rank; otherwise, the sequence has Exact Match rank.

I don't know how to insert the table here. But basically we have one "Exact Match" (to call `Dummy operator*(T&&)`) and one "Conversion" (to call `T& Base::operator*`), thus the "Exact Match" is the "best viable function". And (§13.3.3.2):

> If there is exactly one viable function that is a better function than all other viable functions, then it is the
>   one selected by overload resolution

That's why the `Dummy operator*(T&& )` is preferred.

Now, why does my proposal work? In that case, our two options are:

```
template <typename T>
Dummy operator*(T&& );

T& DerivedA<int>::operator*();
```

So we have two "Exact Match" candidates - though one of them is through a template and one of the criteria for choose better viable functions is (§13.3.3.1):

> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function
>   F2 if ...
>
> - F1 is a non-template function and F2 is a function template specialization

Hence, in this case, we pick the `DerivedA::operator*`. Which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> I have no control at all over free operator, and can't move derived classes to different namespace.

If you cannot move the derived classes to a different namespace from the user's perspective but *can* move them in the code itself, you can do this:

```
 namespace ns {
   namespace ns_ {
     template <typename T>
     struct Base {
       T x;

       T& operator*() { return x; }
     };

     template <typename T>
     struct DerivedA : Base<T> {};
   }

   using namespace ns_;
 }
```